Initializing a std::string_view with a C-style string literal
std::string_view objects only have a view over an object such as a std::string, and modifying the value of a string used to initialize a string_view will invalidate it.
Now, if I initialize a string_view with a C-style string literal, as follows:
std::string_view s{ "Hello, world!" };

Here "Hello, world!" is just a literal, so why does this work? Does the std::string_view constructor create a std::string or C-style string in memory? Or does writing a C-style string literal create an object in memory? If this is the case, how is it handled in terms of memory location and lifespan?

String literals permanently exist in a fixed memory location while the program is running, regardless of string_view.

Typically a string_view consists of a pointer to the character data and a length. Both of these can easily be obtained from a string literal. There's no need to allocate any additional objects.

This is a string: std::string("Hello, world!") or "Hello, world!"s.  This is a C-string literal "Hello, world!".  A C-string literal has a life span of the program.

A string_view relies on the object it is providing a view for to exist for as long as it does.  A string literal is a statically allocated array of (const) char, so it will exist until the program terminates (i.e. it will outlive the string_view).

Interestingly, (at least in the case of MSVC, but maybe this is in the specification) the program will only allocate the memory for a string literal once. I.e. if you do std::string_view s{ "Hello World!\n" }; std::string_view t{ "Hello World!\n" }; s and t's member _Mydata both point to the same address.

@dmedine merging the storage of duplicate string literals is up to the compiler/linker to decide and is not guaranteed. In fact, some compilers have an option to disable that behavior.

From cppreference:

evaluating a string literal results in a string literal object with static storage duration.

So, when I call:
std::string_view s{"Hello World"};

The program will statically allocate this char string before the program begins, and so the subsequent constructor of the string_view takes in a pointer to static memory.
As for your question about the lifetime of a string literal, it is static, meaning it gets allocated before the program begins, and deallocated when the program ends. std::string_view has no hand in this, and the same behavior would be observed if we used the string literal in any other context.


std::string_view objects only have a view over an object such as a std::string

That is incorrect. cppreference.com says:

The class template basic_string_view describes an object that can refer to a constant contiguous sequence of CharT with the first element of the sequence at position zero.

A string literal satisfies that requirement without needing to create a std::string for it.

why does this work?

Because std::string_view allows it. It has a constructor which accepts a const char* C-style string, which a string literal decays into.

Does the std::string_view constructor create a std::string or C-style string in memory?

Neither. A string literal exists in static memory for the entire lifetime of the program. The string_view merely points at the string literal's data.

Sometimes I wonder why this was put in the standard. Remy do you know any case where constructing an std::string_view is the best practice in managing an char[N] or const char*? +1 for a very good answer.

I don't understand what you are asking. string_view does not manage anything. It's just a view into an existing sequence of characters, nothing more. So why shouldn't it be allowed to view a string literal?

My question exactly. So it is just a view then. What does this even mean? A View. I guess understanding what the term a View means will answer my question.
